# Converting non-seekable Stream to byte[] gives ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, httpwebresponse

I'm trying to `GetResponseStream` from a *GET* request and convert this into `byte[]`. The *Stream* is non-seekable so I can't access `stream.Length`. `response.ContentLength` is unreliable.

```cs
private byte[] streamToBytes(Stream stream, int bufferSize = 4096)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        int read = 0;
        int pos = 0;
        List<byte> bytes = new List<byte>();
        while (true) { // `bufferSize > read` does **not** mean stream end
            while (bufferSize == (read = stream.Read(buffer, pos, bufferSize))) {
                pos += read;
                bytes.AddRange(buffer);
            }
            if (read > 0) {
                byte[] _buffer = new byte[read];
                Array.Copy(buffer, _buffer, read);
                bytes.AddRange(_buffer);
            } else break;
        }
        return bytes.ToArray();
    }
```

An `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` gets thrown on the `Read` in the second iteration of the `while` loop. [**MSDN says**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.io.stream.read)

> `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` *offset* or *count* is negative.

I know this can't be true because *offset* (`pos`) is `0 + read >= 0` and *count* (`bufferSize`) is `4096` so why am I getting exceptions thrown at me?

I'm trying to keep `streamToBytes` as generic as possible so I can use it in future *async* methods, too.

---

If how the request is made helps, here are the relevant bits

```cs
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create((new Uri("http://google.com")).ToString());
request.Method = "GET";
request.KeepAlive = true;
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
byte[] responseBytes = streamToBytes(stream);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
stream.Read(buffer, pos, bufferSize)
```

to

```
stream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)
```

Comment: This is what I get for not reading all of the MSDN page, huh? Will accept when possible.

Comment: Now I've fixed this, I've discovered it looks like I can't also assume `bufferSize > read` means end of stream. :(

Answer (score 4):

As a simpler alternative:

```
using(var memStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    stream.CopyTo(memStream);
    return memStream.ToArray();
}
```

---

Your code has two mistakes:

1. The `offset` on `Read` is an offset into the buffer, not the position in the stream (as @Ulugbek already noted). This means you don't need the `pos` variable anymore.
2. You cannot assume that `bufferSize == read` even before the stream reached its end. You need to check for `> 0` instead.

So your reading loop becomes:

```
while ((read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)) > 0)
{
    bytes.AddRange(buffer.Take(read));
}
```

You can now drop the special handling for the last block. Simplifying your code to:

```
private byte[] streamToBytes(Stream stream, int bufferSize = 4096)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    int read = 0;
    List<byte> bytes = new List<byte>();
    while ((read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)) > 0)
    {
        bytes.AddRange(buffer.Take(read));
    }
    return bytes.ToArray();
}
```

Using `List<byte>` instead of `MemoryStream` isn't a great idea either. `AddRange` need to iterate over the bytes individually, instead of using a low level copy operation. Replacing the list with a memory stream, the code becomes:

```
private byte[] streamToBytes(Stream stream, int bufferSize = 4096)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    int read = 0;
    using(var bytes = new MemoryStream())
    {
        while ((read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)) > 0)
        {
            bytes.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        return bytes.ToArray();
    }
}
```

You could even split it into two parts, one does the copying into the memory stream, the other handles the creating of the memory stream and turning it into a byte array:

```
private static void CopyStream(Stream source, Stream destination, int bufferSize = 4096)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    int read = 0;
    while ((read = source.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)) > 0)
    {
        destination.Write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}

private static byte[] StreamToBytes(Stream stream, int bufferSize = 4096)
{
    using(var memStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        CopyStream(stream, memStream);
        return memStream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

This is probably very similar to what `Stream.CopyTo` does internally.

Comment: Will this still work (i.e. get only the new bit) if I move to async/downloading large files?

Comment: @PaulS. net 4.5 has a `CopyToAsync` method, so porting it to an async version shouldn't be hard. But for large files its a bad idea to allocate a byte array to contain the whole file.

Comment: I was thinking of saving to disk between invocations for the large files and perhaps introducing some kind of limit on how many total bytes each invocation can do. Your latest edits are really helpful for me, thanks!

Comment: Actually introducing an optional limit on the number of reads is much easier, I've do that (so `number of returned bytes < bufferSize * reads`) and I can check for a length `0` return to end it. Gone with your `Write` to `MemoryStream`, too. Thank you again.